# How to remove bone keyframe without interrupting location and rotation object

Tags: animation, keyframes

i started to animate body movement at first and the location and everything, and then i thought about coming back to animate the face. Now that i'm done animating the body, i went to the first keyframe, highlight the face and remove all the keyframe available, so i can animate the face. But unfortunately, it also remove the object location and rotation. What do i do so that only the keyframe of the face is remove instead of removing the object's location and rotation too. I cant animate the face because when i animate the body, i insert keyframe on all selected bone.

is there any way i could hide the location and rotation of the object and delete the face bone keyframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this, is lock all other channels, then delete, then unlock the others like this:

[image]

Comment: heyy, that work. Of course, i forgot that you can do that. sorry for the noob question. I'm still getting used to animation. thanks man :D

Comment: No problem. We all started at one point. And I asked noob questions a lot here 